# how docker containers can communicate in a Mesos/Marathon setup

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I have created two docker containers for Apache Airavata. Let's say they are container A nad B. Container B is dependent upon container A. after starting  container A, I have to provide the A's IP address as an environment variable to container B. Now container B's start up script will make changes in configuration file for container B. After this changes container B can communicate with container A.

when I was doing the setup in a local docker environment I manually created the containers and passed the required values during container creation.

```
docker run -i -d --name pga --env SERVER_HOST=172.17.1.84 --env SERVER_PORT=8930 -p 8787:80 -t pga:test
```

In a Mesos/marathon environment docker can be created in any Mesos slave system. Now how can I make the communication happened between containers?
I am launching docker jobs with marathon framework.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you described can be solved by using a service discovery mechanism (such as [Mesos DNS](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns) or [Marathon Event Bus](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/event-bus.html)) in conjunction with some custom tooling (i.e. a script developed by you). Basically you need to write a script that runs inside container B and uses service discovery to find out container A's IP address, modifies the configuration file, and possibly restarts the service.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you to try [consul](https://consul.io/) for service discovery. Also since you use Mesos/Marathon it may be useful to try [Apollo](https://github.com/Capgemini/Apollo), which also based on consul.